# Dynamics CRM Plugin-For a input publication value, search for subscription, if found add it to the contact on create/update

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

The below code seems to work when a contact is created, for input value publication it searches and associates an existing subscription. But the same code wont work for update of a contact. Any opinions as to why this may be happening in my plugin?

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(publication))
{
    //Query for existing Publication
    var publicationQuery = new QueryByAttribute("msdynhcp_publicationnewsletter");
    //publicationQuery.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
    publicationQuery.Attributes.AddRange("msdynhcp_publicationname");
    publicationQuery.Values.AddRange(publication);
    publicationQuery.TopCount = 1;

    //Call Query
    EntityCollection publicationIds = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(publicationQuery);

    if (publicationIds.Entities.Count > 0)
    {
        //Query for existing subscription
        var subscriptionQuery = new QueryExpression("msdynhcp_subscription");

        var linkedContact = new LinkEntity("msdynhcp_subscription", "contact", "msdynhcp_contactlookup", "contact" + "id", JoinOperator.Inner);
        linkedContact.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        linkedContact.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("contact" + "id", ConditionOperator.Equal, ContactId);
        subscriptionQuery.LinkEntities.Add(linkedContact);

        var linkedPublication = new LinkEntity("msdynhcp_subscription", "msdynhcp_publicationnewsletter", "msdynhcp_publicationlookup", "msdynhcp_publicationnewsletter" + "id", JoinOperator.Inner);
        linkedPublication.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        linkedPublication.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("msdynhcp_publicationnewsletter" + "id", ConditionOperator.Equal, publicationIds[0].Id);
        subscriptionQuery.LinkEntities.Add(linkedContact);

        subscriptionQuery.TopCount = 1;

        //Call Query
        EntityCollection subscriptionIDs = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(subscriptionQuery);

        if (subscriptionIDs.Entities.Count == 0)
        {
            //New Subscription
            var crmSubscription = new Entity("msdynhcp_subscription");
            crmSubscription["msdynhcp_utcdatetimestamp"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
            crmSubscription["msdynhcp_enabledactive"] = true;

            //Call Create
            var id = organizationService.Create(crmSubscription);

            //Call Associate
            organizationService.Associate("msdynhcp_subscription", id, new Relationship("msdynhcp_contact_new_subscription_contactlookup"),
                new EntityReferenceCollection(new List<EntityReference>() { new EntityReference("contact", new Guid(ContactId)) }));
            //Call Associate
            organizationService.Associate("msdynhcp_subscription", id, new Relationship("msdynhcp_new_publicationnewsletter_new_subscription_publicationlookup"),
                new EntityReferenceCollection(new List<EntityReference>() { new EntityReference("msdynhcp_publicationnewsletter", publicationIds.Entities[0].Id) }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define “wont work”. It throws an exception? Post the message. Id doesn't throw an error but the contact isn't updated? Why did you conclude that? Are you refreshing `organizationService` after updating it?

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions but the contact isn't updated with the relevant subscription. In summary, contact saves after the update, no subscription added even though publication is associated with a subscription and no exceptions thrown. I am not refreshing the organizationService after the update, am I supposed to, can you clarify further? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to "teach a man to fish" rather then telling you what's wrong, why don't you just debug it yourself?  You can use the Plugin Registration tool to [create a serialized version of the plugin context, and then debug that yourself](https://engagesoftware.com/news/post/4242/how-to-debug-a-plugin-in-dynamics-crm-2015-online).

Comment: this is not an answer :P

Comment: Your Mom's not an answer @GuidoPreite... https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/f2/b2/13/f2b21314f7d239dd5ec98bfee48c1702.jpg

Comment: ahahahahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the whole plugin logic but if it works on create and does not work on update then most likely, you are expecting in your plugin an attribute that is simply not there. When you create an entity, you have to fill all the required fields (at least if you do that on the web form) and all this attributes are there in your Target in InputParameters of the plugin. But when you are updating entity, only the attributes that are modified are in the Target from InputParameters (and of course some standard attributes like modifiedon, modifiedby etc.). So, most likely, your plugin checks if some attribute is null (this first check for `publication` looks suspicious, but I can't tell if that's it, as it's not the full code. To be sure that the attribute is there, get it from PostImage/PreImage not Target (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#Anchor_5)